# How to achieve rotating form effect in wpf

Tags: wpf

I would like to make a rotating form WPF effect like the one in the norton antivirus 2010.

The effect is a rotating form that changes the contents when the other side is shown. But the axis is not in the center of the form but moves from side to center and back. Like a three step effect.

The rotating form can be seen at 8' 07" in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3hHPdgi9Nk&feature=related (I'm sad but this was the only video I found on YouTube)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a description of the transform so that we don't have to download 8+ minutes of video?

Comment: slugster, i changed the contents as you suggested.

Comment: To clarify the transform a bit; it's an animation where the form is turned around, so that it gives the impression of having one UI on the "front side" and another on the "back side".

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Thriple stuff on CodePlex:  http://thriple.codeplex.com/

It's almost exactly what you're after.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I did not examine the details, but I know that Microsoft's *patterns & practices team* also uses a similar animation in their *"StockTrader Reference Implementation"* for the *"Composite Application Guidance"*. They sub-classed the `TabControl` and added some animation to it. I think the relevant code parts can be found here:

- [AnimatedTabControl.Desktop.cs](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/41709#839826)
- [Generic.xaml](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/41709#839767)

Answer (score 0):

just verify this link. It has code as well as the Sample.

From the Sample take the TransitionPresenter link from the left panel and choose the 3D Rotate item from the listbox. Then select the images from the top list. You can see the same effect in the video. I saw some initial sanp of the video and may be this link can help you.

http://bot.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yes, the left 3d spin effect is the one I would like to achieve, but how to do that with a windows form and not with a control inside a form?